# Redeeming sets on Magic the Gathering Online

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-online

I just got a full set from a treasure chest and was wondering if I need to open it to redeem it or if I need to leave the set in my Other Product section of MTGO.

Comment: I don't know, but here are the redemption rules: https://magic.wizards.com/en/gameinfo/products/magiconline/redemption

Comment: @AulisRonkainen Yeah I looked at those and it wasn't clear to me whether I should open it or not.

Comment: It seems to me that the line "To redeem a set, you must have at least one of every card in the set you are trying to redeem in your collection." indicates what you need to do here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to redeem the set you will need to open the full set.

However you can always try purchasing a Redemption Request for the set that you have before you open it, the request will stay in your Other Products until it can either be processed using the cards in your inventory, or two redemption attempts have failed.